# BackgroundGeoLocation cordova plugin doesnt work

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

Im trying to use this plugin as it is exactly what i need for my project
the only problem is when i follow the example on the website

https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

The moment i get to the part of 
`var bgGeo = window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation;`

and then run the website it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundGeoLocation' of undefined

i got the latest cordova

Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
It's just that the plugin isn't ready at this time.

You must not forget to put the initialization code in the onDeviceReady function!

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
    ... 
}
```